# Complex conditions in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I have the following code, and if this was in C# or VB.Net it would apply as intended, but I am not so sure that it will work in VBScript?

```
 if (sal = "23"  or sal = "6") and error_flag = 0 then
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: I wanted to evaluate the conditions in parenthesis as a single complex condition. So its like controlling the order of evaluation of conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should work fine.  VB is just like VBScript when it comes to basic syntax such as this.

Answer (score 0):

If variable "sal" is string there won't be problem vice a versa if it's not then you need to remove double quotes from integer values